# c++ driver mongodb connection options

Tags: c++, mongodb, connection-string

It seems that c++ drivers doesn't accept mongodb connection uri format.
There's no documentation on how i should create connection string, any guess?

I need to connect to a replica set with 3 servers, and set readPreference options.

Comment: uhm, "no documentation"??? http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_replica_set.html

Comment: ok, tell me where connection string format is explained :)

Comment: It is explained somewhere, but there is no link from the relevant C++ API documentation, and the implementation is buggy, as was pointed out in an answer below.

Comment: Maybe rename this question to "Connecting to a replica set in MongoDB C++ driver"

Answer (score 3):

## Create a connection to a replica set in MongoDB C++ client

Until the problems explained in [@acm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651520/2577176) are resolved, I have found a workaround to the bad Connection Strings of the C++ driver. You can create a `DBClientReplicaSet` using a vector of hosts and ports this way:

```
//First create a vector of hosts
//( you can ignore port numbers if yours are default)  

    vector<HostAndPort> hosts;
    hosts.push_back(mongo::HostAndPort("YourHost1.com:portNumber1"));
    hosts.push_back(mongo::HostAndPort("YourHost2.com:portNumber2"));
    hosts.push_back(mongo::HostAndPort("YourHost3.com:portNumber3"));

//Then create a Replica Set DB Client:

    mongo::DBClientReplicaSet connection("YourReplicaSetName",hosts,0);

//Connect to it now:

    connection.connect();

//Authenticate to the database(s) if needed

    std::string errmsg;
    connection.auth("DB1Name","UserForDB1","pass1",errmsg);
    connection.auth("DB2Name","UserForDB2","pass2",errmsg);
```

Now, you can use insert, update, etc. just as you did with `DBClientConnection`. For a quick fix, you can replace your references to `DBClientConnection` with `DBClientBase` (which is a parent to both `DBClientConnection` and `DBClientReplicaSet`)

**Last pitfall:** if you are using getLastError(), you must use it with the aimed database name like this:

```
connection.getLastError(std::string("DBName"));
```

cause otherwise it will always return "command failed: must log in" as described in [this JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10318).

## Set the read preferences for every request

You have two ways to do that:

### SlaveOK option

It lets your read queries be directed to secondary servers.

It takes place in the query options, which are at the end of the parameters of `DBClientReplicaSet.query()`. The options are listed in [Mongo's official documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.1.0/namespacemongo.html#a7261673f7552ae9ee3a055f8f3962d8c)

**The one you would look for** is `mongo::QueryOption_SlaveOk`, which will allow you to have reads made on secondary instances.

This is how you should call query();

```
connection.query("Database.Collection",
     QUERY("_id" << id),
     n,
     m,
     BSON("SomeField" << 1),
     QueryOption_SlaveOk);
```

where n is the number of documents to return (0 if you don't want any limit), m the number to skip (defaults to 0), the next field is your projection and the last your query option.

To use several query option, you can use `bitwise or |` like this :

```
connection.query("Database.Collection",
     QUERY("_id" << id),
     n,
     m,
     BSON("SomeField" << 1),
     QueryOption_SlaveOk | QueryOption_NoCursorTimeout | QueryOption_Exhaust);
```

### Query::readPref option

The [Query object has a readPref](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_query.html#ab2c5a34d35460d795903d11d7a71824d) method which sets read preferences for a special query. It should be called for each query.

You can pass different arguments for more control. [They are listed here](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.1.2/namespacemongo.html#a36e928fe9d92b2bcf9d7d1b6d9045e82).

So here's what you should do (I did not test that one cause I can't right now but it should work just fine)

```
/* you should pass an array for the tags. Not sure if this is required.
Anyway, let's create an empty array using the builder. */

BSONArrayBuilder bab;

/* if any, add your tags here */

connection.query("Database.Collection",
     QUERY("_id" << id).readPref(ReadPreference_SecondaryPreferred, bab.arr()),
     n,
     m,
     BSON("SomeField" << 1),
     QueryOption_NoCursorTimeout | QueryOption_Exhaust);
```

**Note**: if any readPref option is used, it should override the slaveOk option.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how read options from your example  (e.g. SlaveOK etc) are working with query.readPref(mongo::ReadPreference_Nearest, arr); Secondary only, Primary only etc. Can I specify them both? Can I use Secondary only without specifying SlaveOk ? 
Thank you

Comment: I think you can use both slaveOk or readPrefs if you want more control options. It should be analogous to [Node Mongoclient as explained here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#read-preference). So readPrefs should override any SlaveOk value. It is still to be set at a query level, though. I'll edit my post to add those details.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) documentation for details on the connection string format.

(code links below are to 2.2.3 files)

To use a connection string with the C++ driver, you should use the [`ConnectionString`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08/src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h#L185) class. You first call the [`ConnectionString::parse`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08/src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h#L259) static method with a connection string to obtain a [`ConnectionString`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08/src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h#L185) object. You then call `ConnectionString::connect` to obtain a [DBClientBase](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08/src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h#L931) object which you can then use to send queries.

As for read preference, at the moment I do not see a way to set the read preference in the connection string for the C++ driver, which would preclude a per-connection setting.

However, the implementation of `DBClientBase` returned by calling `ConnectionString::parse` with a string that identifies a replica set will return you an instance of [DBClientReplicaSet](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08/src/mongo/client/dbclient_rs.h#L412). That class honors `$readPreference` in queries, so you can set your read preference on a per-query basis.

Comment: It seems it doesn't accept uri connection string like "mongodb://..." as described in documentation. That's the problem.

Comment: @user1365836 I just tried it out, and you are correct. A connection string like `mongodb://localhost:27017` does not work correctly. However, to connect to a single machine it does seem to work to just pass `localhost:27017` to `ConnectionString::parse`. See if dropping the `mongodb://` prefix works better. Also, please file a ticket here: https://jira.mongodb.org

Comment: It uses old format like replicaset/ip,ip,ip or something similar (you can't find doc anymore!). I'm very  disappointed: c++ driver, that should follow mongodb development doesn't work as expected. We should open a big ticket "please make c++ driver working as in docs". Try readPreference or secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS params, if you can! Very disappointed.

Comment: @user1365836 I agree that it is unfortunate that the C++ driver is out of alignment with the documentation, and I agree that it is frustrating that it doesn't support all of the options. However, your best course of action is to file tickets with 10gen when you find issues: it helps the developers know where to focus their efforts, and it lets you track progress on the issues you care about, and it helps others who encounter the same problem. So I strongly encourage you to file tickets for all of the above problems!

Answer (score 1):

Since the current C++ drivers still do not accept the standard mongodb connection URIs, I've opened a ticket:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-2
Please vote for it to help get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you can set read Preference before send a read request by call "readPref" method of your Query object. I'v not found a way to set read Preference on mongo collection object yet.

Comment: oh,i'm wrong, mongo connection object, not the mongo collection object.